Forward pass of RecurrentPPO algorithm not producing the right shaped tensor
I am performing a forward pass for RecurrentPPO algorithm (part of sb3-contrib) library. The policy used is the MlpLstmPolicy. I have 3 action classes. Hence ideally the action_logits returned have to be tensors of shape (1,3). I am getting a tensor of shape (1,). Why is this happening?
action_logits, values, log_prob, lstm_states = model.policy.forward(
        obs_tensor, lstm_states=lstm_states, episode_starts=episode_starts_float)

